# Request an address from a range of IP-addresses using dhclient dhcp-requested-address

Tags: dhcp, ip-address, dhclient

I am in a situation where I need ***myDevice*** (ubuntu), when connected to router, to have any IP address in the range of ***192.168.1.20*** to ***192.168.1.40***. I am aware that adding the line

`send dhcp-requested-address 192.168.1.20;` to the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

would assign my device with the same address. It fails to do so if another device connected in the same network holds the same address. In such scenario I want the dhclient to request for the next IP address in the specified range i.e ***192.168.1.21*** . How do I achieve it?